# laravel livewire session display issue custom blade layouts issue

Tags: php, laravel

session message is not printing in layout blade file.
livewire component code:

```
session()->flash('message', [
            'text'=>'create successfully',
            'type'=>'success',
        ]);
```

layouts/admin.blade.php

```
@if (session()->has('message.text'))
                            <div class="alert
                                {{ session('message.type') === 'success' ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger' }} alert-dismissible fade show"
                                data-cy="alert-message"
                            >
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                <strong>{{ session('message.text') }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        @endif
```

> | GET|HEAD | owner/category                   | category                 | App\Http\Livewire\Owner\Category\CategoryView        | web           |
> |        |          |                                  |                          |                                                      | auth:owner    |
> |        | GET|HEAD | owner/category-create/{id}       | category.create          | App\Http\Livewire\Owner\Category\CategoryCreate      | web           |
> |        |          |                                  |                          |                                                      | auth:owner    |
> |        | GET|HEAD | owner/category-update/{id}       | category.update          | App\Http\Livewire\Owner\Category\CategoryUpdate      | web           |
> |        |          |                                  |                          |                                                      | auth:owner

Comment: {{ dd(session()) }} to check if session exists for the route or not

Comment: it's not reaching

Comment: You need to check whether the route has web or auth middleware applied - run `php artisan route:list` in the terminal and see which middleware is applied for the route - right most column lists middleware for the route in the output

Comment: web auth:owner is used in catageroy component

Comment: Can you post the output of route:list in a code block

Comment: i have just added you can check it out

Comment: Is `owner` a custom guard that you have defined? Try removing the guard `owner` from the middleware declaration on route. Like `middleware(['auth'])` instead of `middleware(['auth:owner'])` and see

Comment: not showing the message the session msg

Comment: If you try to `dd(session())` in the mount() method of your livewire component after changing the middleware declaration on route do you get null or a Session object

Comment: getting null values

Comment: Strange that session() returns null. Can you post your routes file?